# Customize OWA to Office365 Transition Page

Tags: customization, outlook-on-the-web, office-365

We are implementing office 365 email accounts for our organization.

To start the users still go to our regular outlook webmail login screen (xyzmail.xyz.org)
They enter their credentials and click sign in:

[image]

The office 365 users are then redirected to this page (xyzmail.xyz.org/**owa/auth.owa**):

[image]

**Is there anyway to customize this transitional page or skip it altogether?**